# Looping through the directories

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, awk

```
paths=$1
files=$2
for dir in ${paths[@]}
do
    newdir=${dir##*/}
    newpath=(/pathname)
    val=`mkdir -p ${newpath}/${newdir}`
    echo ${val}

    for file in "${dir}"/*; do
        if [[ -f $file && $file = *.@(c|cc|cpp|h) ]]; then
            cp ${file} ${val}
        fi
    done
done
```

I want  to loop through the directories and copy the filenames in the newly created val directory..but I am unable to print the value of val. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to treat $paths as an array in `${paths[@]}`, but you populate it with a single value: `paths=$1`.

Comment: ohh but there will be multiple paths assigned like this          
Path1: /home/demo/path0

PATH2: /home/demo/path1

PATH3: /home/demo/path2

Comment: That's just a string, not an array. Array is declared in this way: `paths=(/home/demo/path0 /home/demo/path1 /home/demo/path2)`.

Comment: @user6690412 I see you accepted an answer but that answer isn't actually related to your main problem and doesn't address your other problems. Copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net, fix the problems it tells you about, and then ask a new question if you still need help but this time show us how you're calling your script too as that is the key to solving your main problem (i.e. how to populate `paths` and `files` correctly).

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning the output of

```
mkdir -p ${newpath}/${newdir}
```

to val, however this command does not output anything, thus you can't print anything. (You can, but the output is empty)

If you want to have anything in val, do it first and use val to create the directory, like:

`val="$newpath/$newdir"`

`mkdir "$val"`

this way you have the created directory in your variable.

Comment: Thank you.. this worked, but however, it only creates one directory..while I have mentioned multiple directories in the paths variable.

Comment: @user6690412 `$paths` is not an array (even though you're trying to treat it as one on line 3 of your script), it can hold only one value. you've set it to "$1", the first argument to the script.

Comment: `newpath` is an array so using it like a scalar is wrong even though it'll "work" as bash will treat it like the first element of the array. This just addresses one of the many problems in the OPs script, though, and after fixing this part the OPs script still won't be close to working.